# Entity Framework wrong migration if DatabaseGeneratedOption.Indentity exists in model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

In my Asp.Net MVC project I use Entity Framework Code First.
Today I tried to create a new entity

```
public partial class Contract
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
}
```

I have generated migration for this model with up method:

```
public override void Up()
{
    CreateTable(
        "dbo.Contracts",
        c => new
            {
                Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                Created = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);      
}
```

Which is fine and works perfectly. But now I want to generate Created property in DB on insertion. To do that I used `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity` (from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedoption(v=vs.110).aspx)). So now I have a model like this

```
public partial class Contract
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
}
```

And have a bit different migration file with up method:

```
public override void Up()
{
    CreateTable(
        "dbo.Contracts",
        c => new
            {
                Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
                Created = c.DateTime(nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "GETUTCDATE()"),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);    
}
```

Which is wrong. The main difference is that Id property isn't identity in this configuration.

Could anyone explain why this happens?
To solve this problem I used `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed`, but I'm still confused why wrong migration file is generated for `Identity` option.

**UPD:**
Just checked that I have a proper migration file if I add `Key` and `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity` to Id property too.

```
public partial class Contract
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Well, probably by convention EF assumes single identity column per table. You may need to mark explicitly the `Id` property with `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` as well.

Comment: @IvanStoev, I have the same thoughts, but didn't find anything in doc on this problem. Moreover, many sample projects uses this approach.